# Android Studio - Import data from csv and show in text (app crashes)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to import data from a csv file but my application crashes everytime. Below is my code that I have written. I receive no errors.

My main aim is to import data from the specified csv file and put in the variable called count_car. I want to show the value in the text box when I click the button. But I could not import the data from csv file.

```
package com.example.deneme2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.String;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView text_zeros = findViewById(R.id.TextNumberZero);
    TextView text_ones = findViewById(R.id.TextNumberOne);
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Button button =  findViewById(R.id.button);


    String path = "C:\\Users\\baran\\Desktop\\FALL 2020\\ELEC491\\deneme\\11111111111\\venv\\numberofcars.csv";

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BufferedReader csvReader = null;
            try {
                csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String count_car = null;
            int counting =0;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    if (!((count_car = csvReader.readLine()) != null)) break;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //String[] data = count_car.split(",");
                String count_cars = count_car;
                int count_park= 100;

                String countpark = String.valueOf(count_park);
                String countcars = String.valueOf(count_cars);
                text_ones.setText(countpark);
                text_zeros.setText(countcars);
                counting = counting +1 ;
                if (counting == 50);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

**EDIT 1**

```
package com.example.exceldeneme;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity<number_cars> extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView text_cars = findViewById(R.id.textCars);

        readData();
        String count_park = Arrays.toString(number_of_cars.get(1));
        text_cars.setText(count_park);

    }
    private List<String[]> number_of_cars = new ArrayList<>();
    private void readData() {
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.numberofcars);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
        );
        String line = "";
            try {
                while(((line = reader.readLine()) != null)) {
                String[] tokens = line.split(",");

                number_of_cars.add(tokens);
                Log.d("MyActivity","Just created"+ Arrays.toString(tokens));
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.wtf("MyActivity","Error reading data file on line" + line, e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
}
```

I have changed the code. Now I am using different method. But the app starts to crash again. Is there any opinion? Thanks for answers.

**EDIT 2**

```
package com.example.exceldeneme;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity<number_cars> extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        Button  button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        TextView text_cars = findViewById(R.id.textEmpty);
        TextView text_total_lots = findViewById(R.id.textTotalLots);
        readData();
        int number_of_park = 100;
        text_total_lots.setText(String.valueOf(number_of_park));
        int counter = 0;

        String videoPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.camera_out;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoPath);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

        //Log.d("Selam","This is my message"+ number_of_cars.get(0)[0]);
        //String count_park = number_of_cars.get(0)[2];
        //text_cars.setText(count_park);
        for (String i : number_of_cars.get(0)){
            counter = counter + 1 ;
        }

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int counter = 0;
                for (String i : number_of_cars.get(0)){
                    counter = counter + 1 ;
                }
                for (int i = 1; i < counter-1;i= i +1){
                    String count_park = number_of_cars.get(0)[i];
                    text_cars.setText(count_park);
                    //SystemClock.sleep(1000); //ms
                    Log.d("Selam","SORUN YOK");
                }
            }
        });


    }
    private ArrayList<String[]> number_of_cars = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    private void readData() {
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.numberofcars);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
        );
        String line = "";
            try {
                while(((line = reader.readLine()) != null)) {
                String[] tokens = line.split(",");
                                number_of_cars.add(tokens);
                Log.d("MyActivity","Just created"+ Arrays.toString(tokens));
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.wtf("MyActivity","Error reading data file on line" + line, e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

My final code is here. I have solved my problems and imported data from csv file. I have used videoview to show video. Now I am trying to solve the delay problem.

I want the below for loop function to wait for 1 second or 50 ms. But I could not find the solution.

```
for (int i = 1; i < counter-1;i= i +1){
                    String count_park = number_of_cars.get(0)[i];
                    text_cars.setText(count_park);
                    //SystemClock.sleep(1000); //ms
                    Log.d("Selam","SORUN YOK");
                }
```

If anyone can help, I appreciate it :) Thanks for your answers.

Comment: If your app crashes there was an exception that you did not catch. The logcat should tell you which one.

Comment: `"C:\\Users\\baran\\Desktop\\FALL 2020\\ELEC491\\deneme\\11111111111\\venv\\numberofcars.csv";` Two errors. First: that is a path on a windows pc. It does not exist on an Android device. Second: so you have a FileNotFoundException which you catch, which is good, but after that you continue as if nothing has happened. You should stop/return then

Comment: blackapps thank you for your respond. I solved the crash issue. The path issue that you said is true. When I looked at debug, I saw "W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:/Users/baran/Desktop/FALL 2020/ELEC491/deneme/11111111111/venv/numberofcars.csv: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)". Is there any idea how I can solve this? Or can I import csv file from google drive? It would be even better. Thanks a lot.

Comment: 1. You can indeed import a csv file from google drive if you have the right uri. 2. You can put the csv file with Android Studio in the assets folder of your project. And then at runtime read the file using the assets manager. 3. If the csv file is already on your Android device use full path to the file using the code you published here.

Comment: Thank you again. Can you tell me the method that I should use to import a csv file from google drive? I have the file link as an url from my own drive but I don't know how to implement it. And I put the csv file in res under raw file but it did not work again.

Comment: If you have a google drive url you should download the file first.

Comment: If you use res/raw you need the right code.